# Unable to write/display a OpenCV 16 bit grayscale image to disk

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 2D unsigned short array from which I am trying to create a 16-bit grayscale image using the OpenCV. The code tried is shown below. But when I try to display or save to disk I get a black image with all pixel values zeros.

```
unsigned short Img_2D_array [SIZE_X][SIZE_Y];
for(int vr=1; vr<20; vr++)
    {
        for(int vc=1; vc<16; vc++)
        {
          Img_2D_array[(vr)][(vc)] = (unsigned short)(varPixelValue);
        }
    }
Mat var_mat = Mat(SIZE_X,SIZE_Y,CV_16UC1,&Img_2D_array);
imwrite("testImage.png",var_mat);
```

Note : Edited the code

Comment: Tried your code and is effectively working. Can you post a minimal working example of what you're doing between the array creation and imwrite?

Comment: And what is varPixelValue, SIZE_X, SIZE_Y?

Comment: SIZE_X,Y are the image size and varPixelValue is pixel value in  the range of 0 to 255*255

Comment: That doesn't help at all..

Comment: This is a code snippet, complete code cannot be put here. Code has few inputs like SIZE_X(int),SIZE_Y(int) and varPixelValue(int). I tried to give every detail. If you think you need to know something, be specific.

Comment: Well I cant help you then,  I used your code with = vc * vr  from 0 to 100 each and I got a 100x100 pixel image with a gray gradient. So the code you put IS working.

Comment: @Aram you were correct there was no problem with the code. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the code snippet. But the viewer with which I was viewing the image didn't support 16-bit grayscale images, Nothing to do with the code.